# Challenging Linear Programming Question - Determining Objective Function

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, linear-programming

[image]Working Out:

- X = Num. of bottles sold from Vineyard 1
- Y = Num. of bottle sold from Vineyard 2
- A = Num. of bottles demanded by Rest 1
- B = Num. of bottles demanded by Rest 2
- C = Num of bottles demanded by Rest 3
- D = Num of bottles demanded by Rest 4
- Revenue = 69A + 67B + 70C + 66D
- Cost (Exclusing Shipping) = (23X + 25Y)

  X <= 3500 Y <= 3100

  A <= 1800 B <= 2300 C <= 1250 D <= 1740

I'm really confused with the shipping table. Can someone please explain how to solve this problem.

Comment: The total cost includes the cost to make the wine plus the cost to ship the wine. That's why you have a shipping table. Each bottle that goes from Vineyard $m$ to Restaurant $n$ costs $ShippingTable(m,n)$ dollars.

Comment: How do you write that as a constraint and include it in the cost equation? That is my biggest issue... I'm struggling to understand how to write this

Comment: You produce $X$ bottles from Vineyard 1. You need four variables $A_x$, $B_x$, $C_x$ and $D_x$ such that their sum is $X$ and $A_x$ is the number of bottles sold to Restaurant 1, $B_x$ is the number of bottles sold to Restaurant 2, etc. You need to do the same for Vineyard 2.

Comment: Oh okay.. but how do you solve this if everything is based on two variables...

Comment: You end up with eight variables, each representing the number of bottles shipped from one vineyard to one restaurant.

Answer (score 1):

**Variables**

Let $x_{ij}$ be the number of bottles sold from vineyard $i\in \{1,2\}$ to restaurant $j\in \{ 1,2,3,4\}$.

**Parameters**

Let $c_{ij}$ be the transportation cost from vineyard $i$ to restaurant $j$, let $f_i$ be the production cost for one bottle in vineyard $i$, let $p_j$ be the price of a bottle in restaurant $j$, and finally let $C_i$ and $d_j$ be the capacities and demands in vineyard $i$ and restaurant $j$, respectively.

**Objective function**

You want to maximize profits, that is
$$
\mbox{Maximize } Z= \sum_{i=1}^2\sum_{j=1}^4 (p_j-c_{ij}-f_i)x_{ij}
$$
**Constraints**

Subject to capacity and demand constraints:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^4x_{ij} \le C_i \quad \forall i =1,2\\
\sum_{i=1}^2x_{ij} \le d_j \quad \forall j =1,2,3,4\\
x_{ij}\ge 0\quad  \forall i =1,2,\;\forall j =1,2,3,4
$$